# Таблица и td

Tags: html, css

Вопрос довольно глупый, но быстро погуглив я не нашел необходимого параметра.

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

По умолчанию размер колонки устанавливает самый широкий td из набора. Нужно, что-бы первый td в первой строке был размером 80%, а во второй строке он был 20%. Где и акой параметр отвечает за генерацию блока?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такого параметра нет. В таблице размер столбца устанавливается самой широкой ячейкой в данном столбце.
Есть решение, которое не всем подойдёт:

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
<colgroup>
    <col width="10%">
    <col width="10%">
    <col width="10%">
    <col width="10%">
    <col width="10%">
    <col width="10%">
    <col width="10%">
    <col width="10%">
    <col width="10%">
    <col width="10%">
</colgroup>
<tr>
    <td colspan="8">80</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">20</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>10</td>
</tr>
</table>
```